# Package uninstall blocked with the message "The custom field is in use in historical data filter."

Tags: managed-package, reporting, uninstall

I'm attempting to uninstall a managed package. The uninstall fails with the message "Unable to uninstall package".

Under Problems is listed:

> Component Type: Custom Field
> Name: *<Custom Field Name>*
> Problem: The custom field is in use in historical data filter.

The "Where is this used?" button for the managed custom field in question shows no results.

What do I need to do to clear this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the field is referenced in [Historical Trending](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.reports_historical_setup.htm&type=5).

Setup > Feature Settings > Analytics > Reports & Dashboards > Historical Trending.
Uncheck the field and press save.

---

This will be caused by a report in the Org referencing the custom field.
You will need to find the report and delete it. Also check the custom report types that may be referencing the custom field.